# Viewport initial-scale не работает

Tags: html, viewport

Подскажите, как заставить на мобильном телефоне отображать страницу как на ПК 1:1. Как понимаю initial-scale=1 должен выводить страницу 1:1 как на пк, т.е. не зазумленную во всю ширину, но в итоге он выводит где-то 1:5 от ширины, приходится уменьшать зум руками.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1440, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно изменить вьюпорт. Ширину лучше задать константой width=device-width, т.е. сообщая браузеру, что ширина области просмотра равняется ширине устройства. Использую такой тег

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Страница отображается в полном размере, с возможностью зумировать.